# Laravel: Use same column as option name and its value in select box/drop-down?

Tags: php, forms, eloquent, html-select, laravel-5.8

I'm trying to create a form with a select box in Laravel.

**View**

```
{{ Form::select('cmp_type', $cmp_types, null, $attributes = ['class' => 'form-control']) }}
```

**Controller**

```php
public function showAddCompany()
{
    $cmp_types = cmpTypes::where('status', true)->pluck('type');

    return view('addCompany', compact('cmp_types'));
}
```

This is generating a select box.

```
<select class="form-control" id="cmp_type" name="cmp_type">
    <option value="0">public</option>
    <option value="1">pvt Ltd</option>
    <option value="2">LLP</option>
    <option value="3">NPO</option>
    <option value="4">partnership</option>
    <option value="5">proprietorship</option>
    <option value="6">one person</option>
</select>
```

What can I do to get the select box as?:

```
<select class="form-control" id="cmp_type" name="cmp_type">
    <option value="public">public</option>
    <option value="pvt Ltd">pvt Ltd</option>
    <option value="LLP">LLP</option>
    <option value="NPO">NPO</option>
    <option value="partnership">partnership</option>
    <option value="proprietorship">proprietorship</option>
    <option value="one person">one person</option>
</select>
```

Comment: What is the `type` column? What sort of data is in there?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe what is happening is that when you call `pluck`, you are being returned a numeric array (Collection?) of the values and those numeric keys are being used for the `value` property and the actual value of said key is being used as the display, what if you did:

```
$cmp_types = cmpTypes::where('status' , true )->pluck('type');
$cmp_types = array_combine($cpm_types, $cmp_types);
```

**Reading Material**

[`array_combine`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php)

Answer (score 0):

array_combine() helped me.

the solution is:

```
public function showAddCompany()
    {
        $cmp_types_obj = cmpTypes::where('status' , true )->pluck('type');
        $cmp_types = json_decode($cmp_types_obj);
        $cmp_types = array_combine($cmp_types, $cmp_types);
        return view('addCompany', compact('cmp_types'));
    }
```

my query is returning an object, so i converted it into an array first and then i combined it with itself to get an associate array as

```
['public']=>'public,['private']=>'private',...
```

Comment: You should have accepted the other answer, instead of writing your own from that.